# unable to get the SKU at thank you page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to get the SKU at the `thankyou.php` page in woocommerce. I used the below code :

```
global $product;

$sku=$product->get_sku();
```

But when i check the `$product` with a `var_dump` it shows null. How can i get SKU here?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code anywhere you want to get sku.

```
<?php
 global $product, $woocommerce;
 echo $_product->parent->sku; ?>
```

Comment: I tried this code by putting at the cart page, checkout page and it did not show me any value.

Comment: I used the code that you have posted here and copied it and pasted it. But i wanted to get the SKU within my own function. I did it with another way. Thanks for your consideration.